# ajax post to file function does nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have tried to solve this now for over a week but I just can't seem to figure this out, especially because I get absolutely no error messages.

I want to post a single variable to a local file using jQuery AJAX and this is my code:

JS:

```
var args = "true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true"; //(just an example)
alert("sending request");
$.ajax({type: 'post', dataType: 'text', cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false, url: '/submitvote.php', data: {data: args}, success: function(php_script_response){alert("response: " + php_script_response);}});
```

submitvote.php:

```
<?php
    $pdata = $_POST['data'];
    @file_put_contents('admin/votes.txt', $pdata, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

The first alert() gets executed but it doesn't execute the success function and also posts absolutely nothing to the file. PHP is working fine on my server.

It has worked before and I have just copy-pasted these lines over but it doesn't work now.

Comment: all you need to do is echo something after writing file i.e. `echo 'done';`

Comment: @Gru that didn't fix it

Comment: May I know why you are using `cache, contentType, processData`..? If you process without these properties, everything will work fine.

Comment: Maybe you are not getting error messages because of `@` (since it's purpose is to ignore error messages)?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out:
It was because I messed up the path and I added useless arguments to the $ajax() function (cache, contentType, processData)